# iPhone how to use CAShapeLayer link error with armv7

Tags: iphone, cashapelayer

This probably something really simple, but I have never used CAShapeLayers before, I imported this at the top:

import < QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h >

And the compiler is not complaining, but the linker is with this error:

```
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CAShapeLayer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in myClass.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
```

What do I need to import to make this work?, I am using Xcode 4.2 and building for iPhone iOS 4.3.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Add QuartzCore.framework to your linked libraries under the target's Build Phases.

CAShapeLayer is a part of the QuartzCore framework, so you need to link that to your Xcode project in order to use it.